# On click get list p contents and display in a div

Tags: jquery, html

Having a little trouble with jQuery, please help.

I need to grab the contents of p class="area-desc when class="caption is clicked and display it in class="step-area.

html:

```
<ul id="main-areas" class="group">
                <li>
                    <div class="build-area">
                        <span class="caption bg">Planning</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="area-desc">1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a accumsan dolor. Curabitur rutrum augue nec eros blandit egestas. Aliquam lobortis posuere facilisis. Integer rutrum ullamcorper erat ac tempor. Nulla nec sapien nibh, non consequat dui.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="build-area">
                        <span class="caption bg">Arcitecture</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="area-desc">2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a accumsan dolor. Curabitur rutrum augue nec eros blandit egestas. Aliquam lobortis posuere facilisis. Integer rutrum ullamcorper erat ac tempor. Nulla nec sapien nibh, non consequat dui.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="build-area">
                        <span class="caption bg">Interior Design</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="area-desc">3Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a accumsan dolor. Curabitur rutrum augue nec eros blandit egestas. Aliquam lobortis posuere facilisis. Integer rutrum ullamcorper erat ac tempor. Nulla nec sapien nibh, non consequat dui.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="build-area">
                        <span class="caption bg">Construction</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="area-desc">4Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a accumsan dolor. Curabitur rutrum augue nec eros blandit egestas. Aliquam lobortis posuere facilisis. Integer rutrum ullamcorper erat ac tempor. Nulla nec sapien nibh, non consequat dui.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="step-area bg">

            </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('span.caption').click(function() {
        var step = $('p.area-desc').html();
        $('.step-area').html("<p>" + step + "</p>");
    });
```

At the moment all that code does is grabs the contents of the first p tag and displays it in the desired div.

What I need is a way of showing each description in .step-area on every click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('span.caption').click(function() {
    var step = $(this).parent().next().html();
    $('.step-area').html("<p>" + step + "</p>");
});
```

To display first description on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.step-area').html("<p>" + $('.area-desc:first').html() + "</p>");
});
```

---

Update: **noscript**

**Docs**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/noscript

**Example:**

```
<noscript>
  <style>
    /* override your styles here */
  </style>
</noscript>
```

Comment: ta. What would be the best way to display the first description on page load?

Comment: cheers again. I'm a bit uneasy about setting the descriptions to display:none in my stylesheet, if js is disabled the descriptions won't show at-all, could you suggest something to get around that or is that another post?

Comment: If JS is disabled, the above functionality won't work! But what you can do is have a `<noscript>` section that overrides the styles and set them to be visible - probably with an `!important` specifier.

Comment: Think modernizr is the way to go? So.. .js .area-desc: display none;

Comment: Modernizr wont be of use if Js is disabled at the user's browser. Modernizr uses JS to do all those feature detections.

Comment: I set <html class="no-js" lang="en">

Comment: Ok, but for detecting whether JS is disabled or not, you do not need something like Modernizr. It can easily be done using the built-in cross-browser `<noscript>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
var step = $(this).closest('p.area-desc').html();
```